# Serial Approving

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval

I am facing problem in config Workflow using SharePoint Designer 2010.
I want to create approval Workflow (serial) in Designer 2010. There are four groups:

- first group - (2 approvers)
- second group - (4 approvers)
- third group - (2 approvers)
- fourth group - (3 approvers)

If first group approves it, item goes to the second group, if second group approved, item goes to third, if third group approved, item goes to fourth group. If one of the groups reject Workflow, I want it to stop/end and send email to creator.

Comment: You can use the OOB "Approval - SharePoint 2010" workflow. It works exactly like your requirement.

Comment: I have used this method, but it is not suitable.
when I add  a new item workflow starts and is assigned to all users in the group. I need to workflow assigned to individual user groups

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these step when you setup "Approval - SharePoint 2010" workflow.

1. Create 4 SharePoint groups (GroupA, GroupB, etc...) and assign your approvers accordingly.
2. Add 3 more stages in "Approvers" section. (press the button 3 in image)
3. In stage 1, type in GroupA; stage 2 GroupB; stage 3 GroupC; stage 4 GroupD.
4. Uncheck the checkbox in "Expand groups" (4 in image)
5. Select the other options and "Save" your workflow.

Then workflow should assign 1 task to GroupA first (It is assigning to the group, not the members in groupA). Once GroupA's member approve the task (any ONE member within GroupA), workflow will goto next stage and assign another task to GroupB, etc.

[image]

Comment: Mark, i tried this method, it is not what i need. I need : only one member of a group can approve or reject workflow. thanks!

Comment: You need "only one member of a group" or "any one member of a group" can approve or reject?

Comment: creator must choose one approver from group, and only one member of group (who was selected) can approve or reject item.

Comment: If so, you need to modify the approval workflow with SharePoint designer. You can create 4 initiation parameters "Approvers1", "Approvers2".. etc and specific user can pick approver within a pre-defined group (by default he can choose from any one).[image](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-67-02-metablogapi/8182.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_3222A8BE.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Change the completion condition in SPD 2010 workflow to achieve the goal]

You can always change the completion condition in SPD 2010. That's a really cool feature, i am loving that